# How is "this" passed in C#

Tags: c#, properties, this

I'm trying to understand how "this" gets passed around as a property in C#-6.0 (VS 2015).

```
using System;

public class Person
{
    private Person instance;

    public Person()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public Person myself
    {
        get { return instance; }
        set { instance = value; }
    }

    public string name = "Eddie";

}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person firstPerson = new Person();
        Person secondPerson = firstPerson.myself;

        secondPerson.name = "Bill";
        Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.name);
        Console.WriteLine(secondPerson.name);

        firstPerson.myself = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.name);
        Console.WriteLine(secondPerson.name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My assumption is that when the line:

`Person secondPerson = firstPerson.myself;`

is run, that secondPerson becomes a reference to firstPerson, so when I change the name to "Bill", `firstPerson.name` and `secondPerson.name` are both Bill. But when I run

`firstPerson.myself = new Person();`

I expected `firstPerson.name` and `secondPerson.name` to go back to "Eddie", but it remains "Bill". Why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer as such, but in order to get the desired behaviour you need to introduce a property: public string Name { get { return myself.name; } set { myself.name = value; } } . Then better make the lowercase "name" private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've changed the `Person` instance that `firstPerson.instance` is pointing to, but not the original instance that `firstPerson` refers to.

So `firstPerson` is still pointing to the original `Person` instance (and so `firstPerson.name` returns the value set in the first instance), while `firstPerson.instance` is now pointing to a new (second) `Person` instance.

```cs
Person firstPerson = new Person();            // instance 1
Person secondPerson = firstPerson.myself;     // myself refers to instance 1

secondPerson.name = "Bill";                   // set name in instance 1
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.name);          // get name from instance 1
Console.WriteLine(secondPerson.name);         // get name from myself in instance 1
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.myself.name);   // get name from instance 1 (same as above)

firstPerson.myself = new Person();            // myself refers to instance 2, but firstPerson still refers to instance 1
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.name);          // still getting name from instance 1
Console.WriteLine(secondPerson.name);         // still getting name from myself in instance 1
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.myself.name);   // get name from instance 2 (since firstPerson.myself was reassigned)

firstPerson = new Person();                   // firstPerson and firstPerson.myself point to instance 3
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.name);          // get name from instance 3, which is the default "Eddie"
Console.WriteLine(secondPerson.name);         // still points to instance 1, since that's what it was when it was assigned
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson.myself.name);   // get name from instance 3 (since firstPerson.myself is defaults to the new instance again)
```

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, is it correct to say that when you execute "Person secondPerson = firstPerson.myself;" you are creating a "reference" to instance 1? (a reference in the C++ sense; i.e. firstPerson and secondPerson are referring to the same object)

Answer (score 6):

`this` represent current instance of of a class.

When you are creating new instance of Person `firstPerson.mySelf`, that time it will refer to the new instance of `Person` class.

```
Person firstPerson = new Person();
Person secondPerson = firstPerson.myself; //Here you are referencing to same instance of Person class i.e. same `this`
```

But when you are creating **new instance** of `Person`, it will refer to new `this`

```
firstPerson.myself = new Person();  // New instance new `this`, but still `firstPerson` is referencing to previous instance
```

Explanation with diagram

[image]

> In your case you created new instance of person and stored in `myself`
>   property. but `firstPerson` and `secondPerson` is still pointing to
>   same `this` instance

Comment: new value will store in new instance of `Person` class.... @MongZhu, if this does not answer your question then can you please elaborate what you are trying to say

Comment: the day was probably too long ;) I can't express myself comprehensively apparently :) If OP gets your explanation then this should suffice. Wish you a nice evening :)

Comment: @MongZhu, I guess this is what you were trying to say.. please look at my updated image and last para of my answer

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, Unfortunately I can't view the image (blocked) but thank you for the reply! 'this' still really confuses me and Grant's explanation made more sense to me.

Comment: @Grant's explanation is more clearer than me I agree, but I was trying to explain you about this and how it is working in your program.. but I totally agree that accepted answer is easiest way to explain behavior of your program, +1 to you Grant

Answer (score 3):

The `myself` is just a variable. So when you call

```
Person firstPerson = new Person();
```

you have 2 variables which point to the same instance: `firstPerson` and `firstPerson.myself`. With line

```
Person secondPerson = firstPerson.myself;
```

you introduce third variable which still points to the same instance. Now with

```
firstPerson.myself = new Person();
```

you create second instance and make `firstPerson.myself` point to this instance while the variables `firstPerson` and `secondPerson` still point to the first one.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Grant's line by line comments made it more clear to me but i think you two said the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

1.Actually **class variables** are **reference types**.

2.So when you assign same instance to two variables then they will points to same instance.

3.Whenever you what to point fresh one you need to use **'new' keyword** for assignment.